# Error when adding existing user to Box enterprise account using Java SDK

Tags: box-api, box

I'm trying to add an existing user (a user who registered a personal Box account with his email address) to a Box enterprise account using the Box Java SDK (https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2) like so:

```
String email = "user@domain.com";
String name = "John Doe";
BoxUserRequestObject boxUserRequestObject = BoxUserRequestObject.createEnterpriseUserRequestObject(email, name);
BoxUser createdUser = boxClient.getUsersManager().createEnterpriseUser(boxUserRequestObject);
```

However the SDK fails with an error saying:

```
com.box.boxjavalibv2.exceptions.BoxServerException: User with the specified login already exists
```

How do I programmatically invite that user to my enterprise account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do this with box-java-sdk-v2, however I did create [an issue](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk/issues/61) for adding this functionality to the latest version of our SDK.

You can also check out the REST API documentation for [inviting a user to an enterprise](https://developers.box.com/docs/#users-invite-existing-user-to-join-enterprise). This endpoint will send an email to a user with a personal account, asking them to join your enterprise.

Here's the example cURL call from the docs:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/invites \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-d '{ "enterprise" : { "id" : "42500" } , "actionable_by" : { "login" : "freeuser@box.com" } }' \
-X POST
```